# Git push project with referenced libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I have a project on my client-laptop. (Eclipse - Android)

The project has one referenced library - google play service (`GPS`) - located in the `android-sdk folder`.

It is referenced because I find it kind of useful that when I update GPS, I do not have to add the new version to my project.

Now as I pushed my project to my git-server, I noticed that the project is pushed without the referenced library.

So my question is, is there a way to also include referenced libraries when pushing with git. I was not able to find any setting..

And, what is a good/right way to add external libraries so that they get pushed with the project?

Comment: Is there a reason you are still using eclipse as opposed to Android Studio? Eclipse for Android is no longer being developed. And on Android Studio you would just add GPS to the dependencies and everything would be handled automatically.

Comment: @RogueBaneling Yes there is the reason that I developed the project in eclipse in Windows. Now I am currently changing to Android Studio on Ubuntu (I got dual boot). And now I just wanted to push the project from eclipse windows to my git-server and pull it to Android Studio on Ubuntu. So do you know a way, right now it is just more an educational reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible/recommended. The right thing to do is obviously download the sdk libraries again. With External libraries (not provided by android sdk), you can put the jar in the /libs, and push to git.

Comment: Yes maybe I am thinking in a complicated way... As I am using Android Studio right now my question was just stupid...